# NetworkActivityIndicator not working the same on iPhone and Simulator?

Tags: iphone, spinner, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using the NetworkActivityIndicator to show that my App is doing some work. When I run the app in the simulator, it shows the way I want - basically spinning the entire time until the selected tab loads the data from the server - but when I put the app onto my phone, I only get a split-second of the spinner before it disappears. Usually only spins right before the view appears on the screen.

Ideas?

EDIT: The problem might have to do with the fact I am using a TabBar... In the simulator the ActivityIndicator will spin on Screen/Tab 1 while Screen/Tab 2 is loading. On the phone, I only see the ActivityIndicator for a split second after Screen 2 finally appears.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

// call to spinTheSpinner
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(spinTheSpinner) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

// method to Get the Data from the Server
[self getDataFromServer];

}

-(void)spinTheSpinner {
    NSLog(@"Spin The Spinner");
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doneSpinning) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    [pool release]; 
}

-(void)doneSpinning {
    NSLog(@"done spinning");
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

-(void)getDataFromServer {
    // does a bunch of stuff to retrieve and display data
}
```

Comment: Could you show some code related to this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You turn on the spinner here…

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

But immediately you turn it off…

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doneSpinning) …];
```

Of course it won't show. I'm surprised it shows in the simulator.

The `-doneSpinning` method should be called *after* `-getDataFromServer` is done, or just do

```
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
[self getDataFromServer]; // assumes it is blocking.
app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
```

Comment: Do I not need to used threading for the networkActivityIndicator?

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Still playing with it but it is acting the same. Showing on the Simulator, only showing on the phone after the screen switches. Sometimes on the phone it doesn't show the spinner at all.